# Using Principal Components Analysis (PCA) on binary data

Tags: pca, svd

I am using PCA on binary attributes to reduce the dimensions (attributes) of my problem. The initial dimensions were 592 and after PCA the dimensions are 497. I used PCA before, on numeric attributes in an other problem and it managed to reduce the dimensions in a greater extent (the half of the initial dimensions). I believe that binary attributes decrease the power of PCA, but i do not know why. Could you please explain me why PCA does not work as good as in numeric data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The principal components of 0/1 data can fall off slowly or rapidly,
and the PCs of continuous data too —
it depends on the data. Can you describe your data ?

The following picture is intended to compare the PCs of continuous image data
vs. the PCs of the same data quantized to 0/1: in this case, inconclusive.

Look at PCA as a way of getting an approximation to a big matrix,
first with one term: approximate A ~ c U V<sup>T</sup>, c [Ui Vj].
Consider this a bit, with A say 10k x 500: U 10k long, V 500 long.
The top row is c U1 V, the second row is c U2 V ...
all the rows are proportional to V.
Similarly the leftmost column is c U V1 ...
all the columns are proportional to U.
But if all rows are similar (proportional to each other),
they can't get near an A matix with rows or columns 0100010101 ...
With more terms, A ~ c1 U1 V1<sup>T</sup> + c2 U2 V2<sup>T</sup> + ...,
we can get nearer to A: the smaller the higher c<sub>i</sub>, the faster..
(Of course, all 500 terms recreate A exactly, to within roundoff error.)

[image]
The top row is "lena", a well-known 512 x 512 matrix, 
with 1-term and 10-term SVD approximations.
The bottom row is lena discretized to 0/1, again with 1 term and 10 terms.
I thought that the 0/1 lena would be much worse -- comments, anyone ?

(U V<sup>T</sup> is also written U ⊗ V, called a "dyad" or "outer product".)

(The wikipedia articles
[Singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)
and [Low-rank approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation)
are a bit math-heavy.
An AMS column by
David Austin,
[We Recommend a Singular Value Decomposition](http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/archive/svd.html)
gives some intuition on SVD / PCA -- highly recommended.)