# How to do PCA on dataframe with binary input

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to do PCA on a very large dataframe like this. The column name Qx.y, where x represents the question number, and y represents the answer number for a question. So person1 answers 1 on 3rd problem.

```
        Q2.1 Q2.2 Q2.3 Q3.1 Q3.2 Q4.1 Q4.2 Q4.3 Q4.4 Q4.5......
person1  0    1    0    1    0   0    0    0    1     0
person2  0    0    1    0    1   0    0    0    0     1
   .
   .
   .
```

The thing that I am confused about is unlike ordinary data, this data uses binary number to represent answer value.
Do I have to transform back to ??

```
            Q2 Q3 Q4
  person1   2  1  4
  person2   3  2  5
```

Also, I want to know if certain questions give more weight in different PC? And can we use one question to predict responses to another?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505296/using-principal-components-analysis-pca-on-binary-data

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/csda.pdf

Comment: the top answer from this crossvalidated answer may be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont

Comment: This package may also be useful: https://github.com/andland/SparseLogisticPCA/archive/master.zip